# IIS7 URL Rewrite and Symbols

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I'm migrating from IIS6 with ISAPI_Rewrite to IIS7 using their Rewrite module. I have a "pretty" url that looks like this: /Shop/Q%26A. Of course that it Q&A encoded. IIS7 doesn't seem to like it. Any ideas?

I already set doubleEscaping=true because I use '+' instead of '%20' for spaces. I can't seem to find anything online about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, it just so happens that [Ruslan from the IIS team](http://ruslany.net/) has been helping me with an almost identical problem over the last two days.

IIS (HTTP.sys) will parse your URL for you - for example, http://site///////dir////file serves you the same content as http://site/dir/file. It will leave the query string alone, but at this point, as we are using pretty URLs, the value is not yet in the query string!

[The unencoded URL is stored in a server variable named UNENCODED_URL](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/#Preserving_Original_URL).  You can do something like this to get that value into a capture variable:

```
<rule name="something" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="^/index\.php" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?title={C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

You then map to it with a [back-reference to the condition](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules).

Comment: That worked perfectly!